# Change column filter "All" label in datatable

Tags: javascript, r, dt

I am trying to change the default label appearing in a DataTable (which is "All") to something else, for example to: `"Sélectionner"`.

Here is my code :

```
library(DT)   

datatable(head(diamonds),
          rownames = F,
          class = 'cell-border stripe',
          extensions = c('Buttons', 'Select', 'SearchPanes', 'FixedColumns'),
          selection = 'none',
          filter = 'top',
          options = list(autoWidth = T,
                         dom = 'Bfrt',
                         pageLength = length(head(diamonds)),
                         columnDefs = list(list(width = '150px', targets = list(1,2,3)),
                                           list(width = '300px', targets = list(5))),
                         searchHighlight = TRUE,
                         buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
                         scrollY=600,
                         scrollX=300,
                         scroller = TRUE,
                         deferRender = TRUE,
                         scrollCollapse = F,
                         oLanguage = list("sSearch" = "Rechercher :",
                                          "sZeroRecords" = "Aucun résultat disponible"),
                         oTable = list("aoSearchCols" = "Aloooo")))
```

[image]

I tried different options such as replacing oTable with aoColumns, sSearchCols, aoSearchCols and aoColumnDefs but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Not sure about a fix, but it looks like it is [hardcoded](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/b54070ef941e6588989f4bb604cc13cf2c88a319/R/datatables.R#L588) into `DT:::filterRow()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *callback* ([related GitHub issue 281](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/281)):

```
library(DT)

datatable(head(diamonds),
          filter = 'top',
          callback = JS("$(\"input[type='search']\").attr('placeholder','xyz');")
          )
```

[image]

Or a bit of a hack, assign *datatable* object to a variable, then *gsub*:

```
myDT <- datatable(head(diamonds),
                  filter = 'top')

myDT[["x"]][["filterHTML"]] <- gsub('placeholder=\"All\"', 'placeholder=\"xyz\"', 
                                    myDT[["x"]][["filterHTML"]])

myDT
```